# Moduli space of vector and principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

Consider $G$ a simple Lie group and $X$ a compact Riemann surface with genus $g$. So we can build $M^g$: the moduli space of principal stable $G$-bundles on $X$. Is there a method to describe $M^g$ as the moduli space of some class of holomorphic vector bundles on $X$?